# Read ASCII, fixed-length fields/records with two record-delimiters

Tags: r, excel, ascii, stata, census

I'm sorry if this is too broad but I'm struggling to load archived Census County Business Patterns data. The file format is described as,

"ASCII, fixed-length fields/records with two record-delimiters (carriage return and line feed); record length includes delimiters."

I've tried loading this into excel, R, and Stata. I'm just trying to get the file in a readable format so that I can work with later. I tried reading it into R with read.fwf but I'm really unclear on what widths I should be using. I don't understand the filetype very well. I'm not too familiar with ASCII files and the file suffix doesn't give me much information. Any advice would be very appreciated. I've provided the link to one of the set of files I'm trying to use below.

https://catalog.archives.gov/id/873805

Answer (score 1):

There were some lines with bad data, so I recommend `read_delim` from the package `readr`

```
library(readr)
data <- read_delim("https://catalog.archives.gov/OpaAPI/media/873805/content/arcmedia/electronic-records/rg-029/cbp-files/RG029.CBP85.T2I1?download=true",
                   delim = " ", col_names = FALSE)
data
## A tibble: 32,970 x 6
#      X1 X2    X3                                                                                                                   #X4    X5 X6    
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>                                                                                                             #<dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 11001 ----  " 00000003482800000011566200000049404800248400140400048300029200018300006600003400001600000500000100000100000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 2 11001 07--  "B00000000000000000000000000000000000000001700001200000300000100000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 3 11001 0700  "B00000000000000000000000000000000000000001500001000000300000100000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 4 11001 0720  "B00000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000100000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 5 11001 0740  " 00000000001900000000003500000000019100000500000300000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 6 11001 0750  "A00000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 7 11001 0780  " 00000000001200000000002700000000035100000600000500000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 8 11001 0800  "A00000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
# 9 11001 10--  "A00000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000100000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
#10 11001 1400  "A00000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000100000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000… 11000 23001 " 424…
## … with 32,960 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` with `fill = TRUE` in `base R`

```
data <- read.table("https://catalog.archives.gov/OpaAPI/media/873805/content/arcmedia/electronic-records/rg-029/cbp-files/RG029.CBP85.T2I1?download=true", fill = TRUE)
```

-output

```
str(data)
#data.frame':   32970 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ V1: int  11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 11001 ...
# $ V2: chr  "----" "07--" "0700" "0720" ...
# $ V3: chr  "000000034828000000115662000000494048002484001404000483000292000183000066000034000016000005000001000001000000000000000000" "B000000000000000000000000000000000000000017000012000003000001000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "B000000000000000000000000000000000000000015000010000003000001000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "B000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000001000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ...
# $ V4: int  11000 11000 11000 11000 11000 11000 11000 11000 11000 11000 ...
# $ V5: int  23001 23001 23001 23001 23001 23001 23001 23001 23001 23001 ...
# $ V6: int  4243 4243 4243 4243 4243 4243 4243 4243 4243 4243 ...
```